# _stat returns impossible errno code 132

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, file-io

I have the following program to read a file that exists:

```
const char *path = "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\Technology\\plus\\fs\\D\\TECH\\CUSTOM\\LOG.XML";
struct _stat    lInfo;
int             err = _stat(path, &lInfo);

if (err == 0) {
    return (lInfo.st_mode & _S_IFDIR) != 0;
} else {
    _get_errno(&err);
    printf("Error: %d\n", err);
}
```

On this particular file I am getting `err == 132` where `_stat`, according to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14h5k7ff.aspx), can only return `ENOENT (2)` and `EINVAL (22)`. Error code 132 is `EOVERFLOW`. If I copy the file exactly and rename it `LOG2.xml` and replace this line accordingly:

```
const char *path = "C:\\Users\\myname\\AppData\\Roaming\\Technology\\plus\\fs\\D\\TECH\\CUSTOM\\LOG2.XML";
```

Then everything works just fine. (ie. `errno` is 0 and i get the file information). If I just rename the original file (From `LOG.XML` to `LOG2.XML`) then i get the same error which leads me to believe its a permissions or ownership problem.

**What could be the cause of this error?**

Comment: These old posix functions can't get the job done anymore.  You'll get EOVERFLOW when the file is larger than 4 gigabytes.  That doesn't fit the st_size member.  You'll have to move up to _stati64() or something more Windows-centric.

Comment: @HansPassant The file is 4Kb, and the copy of it works fine, i would have thought it would be more likely to be related to permissions or something like that.

Comment: @HansPassant I used `GetFileAttributesEx` and i was able to get the attributes. I still dont understand fully why `_spec` doesnt work but all of the old `_fopen` commands do. And spec even works still on different files ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this exact problem while upgrading from Visual Studio 2010 SP1Rel to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2.  My file has a modified date of `Sunday, ‎May ‎13, ‎1601, ‏‎5:53:31 PM`, and it appears `stat` no longer works with dates before 1970.

Debugging through the vc14 ucrt, I believe the following lines of code are relevant:

corecrt_internal_time.h

```
#define _BASE_YEAR     70                // The epoch year (1970)
```

loctotime.cpp:common_loctotime_t()

```
yr -= 1900;

_VALIDATE_RETURN_NOEXC(yr >= _BASE_YEAR && yr <= time_traits::max_year, EINVAL, invalid_time)
```

Running `touch` on the file fixed the issue.

On the one hand, it does seem pretty  unreasonable to have file timestamps that predate 1970, but on the other hand it is possible to do (artificially) and somehow it occasionally happens by accident.  Feels like a regression in Visual Studio.

Comment: Wow, that is crazy, i don't know if i still have the setup to reproduce and check this but i would like to check it out.

Comment: Also, I was seeing EOVERFLOW as the errno (not legit according to MS stat doc) when things went bad.

Comment: The 1601 date is a zero FILETIME, which may be used as a flag to indicate "this file should be updated with something newer" or may simply be a bug in the installler.
The underlying issue is that stat is returning EOVERFLOW both for file sizes which cannot fit into 32 bits, and for file times which cannot be represented in 32 bits.

Answer (score -1):

The link where you looked for the error actually contains the Windows API error codes, which are not the same as the C standard library's.

- The header you need is `<errno.h>` which shows that 132 corresponds to EOVERFLOW.
- VS includes the source code of the C runtime library (in a path like C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio VERSIONID\VC\crt\src), so you should step into it with the debugger to find out what's going on in your case.

A quick look on the CRT source code in my VS version suggests that can happen when a file size is too big to be represented in a 32 bit integer. From what you describe, I'm not sure that might your problem (unless the original path is something special, symbolic link, ...?) but you should try your debugger.